# Hide and then unhide Navigation Bar in Sencha Touch

Tags: navigation, touch, extjs, navbar

I know this is possible in the iOS by setting the property `navigationviewcontroller.navigationBar.hidden` to `YES`. I have a login view inside the navigation controller. In this view I need the navigation bar to be hidden, and already is. The problem is: I need the navigation bar to be shown when I push another view.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply hide the navigation bar with this line of code :

```
myNavigationView.getNavigationBar().hide();
```

Hope this help

Comment: I can only test this tomorrow, but it makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But I had to change the code a little bit. In the first sceren of the app, I set the navigation bar to `hidden:true`. Then, when the next view is pushed, I did `myNavigationView.getNavigationBar().show();`, so I could show it again.

Comment: Really will this work ...? I don't think so i tried this out many times but this way is not working i have a similar problem.I have many pages in navigation view and i want to hide navigation bar of the first two pages (i.e) First Page is login screen and then the next view and so on. So what i want is i want to push the login to next view and hide back button or the whole navigation bar from the next and login screen.Help me with this and validation too in sencha touch.I am following same method as given in many tutorials for validation through model but it's not working.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfect when I try the following

To hide;

```
myNavigationView.getNavigationBar().setHidden(true);
```

To show again;

```
myNavigationView.getNavigationBar().setHidden(false);
```